# Firebase Client ( user ) contact form?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase

What would be the easiest way to have a contact form implemented into an Xcode ios app, where the user inputs their email, name and some hidden variables from within the program? 
I'm thinking a firebase service will work well, as I don't want to use the built-in email form. 
The contact form also needs to know if the form was submitted successfully, such as if the internet was out, or the server/service couldn't be reached. Any help or useful links would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Authentication is great, it allows you to sign up/sign in users, so you can store them safely there.

`Auth.auth().createUser` / `Auth.auth().signIn`

The first method will create an auth user and returns you an uid key for that user, so you can use their Database to store anything related to that user using that uid. The second method will login an user and returns the current user logged in uid, so you can manipulate your data. You can make sure they worked by using the completion and checking if error is == nil.

I highly recommend you to use Auth to authenticate them, otherwise you would have to store their emails and passwords on your Database, and you would have to encrypt them.

Check their documentation here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/auth/ios/start